# Solving the same differential equation with many different initial conditions?

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am using ODEINT (python) to solve a system (600x600) of 1st order (complex) differential equations. But I have 600 different initial conditions I want to use. Right now, I am simply using a for-loop and calling ODEINT 600 times, but obviously this takes an incredible amount of time. Is there any quick way of solving the same differential equations with a series of different initial conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the job done faster, you can try using `multiprocessing` to split the task to different processes. `Pool` is a good way to leverage muti-core cpu to solve cpu-bound tasks like this.